# Turning closure output into dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, closures, tidyverse

The following code generates an object of type 'closure'.

```
function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
  if (missing(ncp)) 
    .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
  else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}
```

The output looks like a typical dataframe. However, I cannot manipulate it like a dataframe since it's a function. Is there a way for me to take the output and turn it into a dataframe that I can manipulate and clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function body of a function called `df` from the stats package. If you start a brand new R session and type `df` (not `df()`) in the console, you will get this function body as the output. It is a function or *closure*.

My guess is that you think you have a data frame called `df` that you have deleted or is called something else, but when you have typed `df` into the console you got this function body in response.